# Abort - navigation controller disappeared

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, segue

I get an exception thrown when pressing a button. That button is associated with a segue (part of storyboard.

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Could not find a navigation controller for segue 'changeRooms'. Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController.'
```

The call stack gives no hint about where the exception is thrown. While trying to dig into it I found the following within prepareForSegue: (ChooseRoomVC.m while segueing to the view controller RoomsListTVC.m)

```
NSLog (@"navController1: %@", self.navigationController);
NSLog (@"navController2: %@", [[segue destinationViewController] navigationController]);
```

creates the output:

```
2013-02-16 15:41:57.201 Wohnungsprotokoll[1906:c07] navController1: (null)
2013-02-16 15:41:57.203 Wohnungsprotokoll[1906:c07] navController2: (null)
```

At that stage I sort of expected that the destinationViewController does not yet have a navigationController assigned. Thats why I compared this with the status within other view controller's prepareForSegue. They all produce the same output: (KeysEditVC.m - from here it is segued to ChooseRoomVC)

```
NSLog (@"navControllerx: %@", self.navigationController);
NSLog (@"navControllery: %@", [[segue destinationViewController] navigationController]);
```

Output:

```
2013-02-16 15:41:52.181 Wohnungsprotokoll[1906:c07] navControllerx: <UINavigationController: 0xa22c5d0>
2013-02-16 15:41:52.182 Wohnungsprotokoll[1906:c07] navControllery: (null)
```

So I checked self.navigationController within viewDidLoad (of chooseRoomVC.m) just to see if something went wrong wile segueing to the view controller that has the problem. But that looks good:

```
NSLog (@"navController0: %@", self.navigationController);
```

output:

```
2013-02-16 15:41:52.212 Wohnungsprotokoll[1906:c07] navController0: <UINavigationController: 0xa22c5d0>
```

So, apparently, while my view controller (chooseRoomVC.m) is being executed, somehow and somewhere the navigationController assignment gets lost. I did add similar NSLogs to viewWillAppear and viewWillDisappear and everywhere self.navigationController is set correctly.

I am more than happy to provide code or screenshots etc. but I do not know where to start. Please advise:

Just for completeness: I use storyboard and ARC, iOS 6.1, iOS Simulator as well as iPhone device, with xcode 4.6 on OS-X 10.8.2.

There is just one thing that may be unusual. The view controller I am segueing to when the error is thrown, can be segued to from a number of view controllers. But I am doing that with more than this one and it works fine in all other cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I found it after it took me ages to nail it down and put everything together for the question.

In IB I copied the button that was associated with this segue from another button of the same view. And from copying from this original there was an assignment of an action left. This IBAction method that was supposed to be associated with another button performed some business logic and called

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

So I was segueing further down and returning to the parent view controller at about the same time! 
Naturally that does not work. However, I'll leave it here so that maybe somebody with the same problem finds the root cause quicker than I did.